# Database in offline HTML Android app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile

I want to build my app in HTML, and bundle it as Android application with a single WebView.

How do I access database? (sqlite I guess)

I don't want HTML5 storage, because that's limited -> unreliable.

My solution would be to write a JS interface for storing data, but that feels like reinventing the wheel.

Is there already something that lets my JS talk to SQlite through the webview?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `PhoneGap` http://phonegap.com for not re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: Well PhoneGap looks really great. But it has only HTML5 database which is limited. But they've taken care of the bridge, so it shouldn't be too hard to add support for real database. Thanks!